# VsCode Remote SSH gives error Could not establish connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2, ssh, vscode-remote

I wanted to know how to connect SSH Server using .PEM file with VsCode?

I am unable to connect to remote ubuntu server at AWS using `Remote SSH`. I am using VSCode on Windows 10. I am using `Remote SSH` extension. I have received `Server.PEM` file along with following command from my client:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/Server.pem ubuntu@ec2-55-131-129-128.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I selected `Linux` for platform of remote host in extesion prompt. But I am getting following error:

```
Visual Studio Code

Could not establish connection to "ec2-55-131-129-128.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com".

[Close Remote] [Retry] [More Actions...]
```

If I try with command line SSH get connected without any problem:

```
ssh -i C:\Users\HT\.ssh\Server.pem ubuntu@ec2-55-131-129-128.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```